# React Adding two parents for a child component

Tags: reactjs, components, parent

**State** is the smart component which store all the states of child components

```
import React from 'react';

import TextArea from './Components/TextArea';
class State extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        name: ''
      }
      this.myChangeHandler = this.myChangeHandler.bind(this)


    }
    myChangeHandler = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            [event.target.name]:event.target.value
            
        });
    }
    render() {
      return (
         <div>
           {/* Change code below this line */}
           <TextArea name = {this.state.name}
           myChangeHandler = {this.myChangeHandler}/>
           
           {/* Change code above this line */}
         </div>
      );
    }
  };


export default State;
```

Now TextArea is the child component which share the input value to state.

```
import React from 'react';
import '../style.css';

class TextArea extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
    }
    render() {
      return (
      <div>
        
        <input type="text" onChange= {this.props.myChangeHandler} name="name" value={this.props.name}></input>
        <h1>Hello, my name is:{this.props.name} </h1>
        
      </div>
      );
    }
  };
  

export default TextArea;
```

There are several child components that send the data to state component.
so the app component is used to order the child component.

I need two parents for a child component. please see the image [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEpMP.png)

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import './App.css';
import TextArea from './Components/TextArea'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Route path = "/new" component= {TextArea} />
      </BrowserRouter>
      
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have two "direct" parent for a single component but you can have multiple indirect parents.
Example:

- App is the parent of State
- State is the parent of TextArea
- App is also a parent of TextArea but not a direct one.

This means that you can pass props (data and functions) from the top parent to all of his children.
If you need to pass a function from App to TextArea you need to pass it by State.
Here a [tutorial](https://scotch.io/courses/getting-started-with-react/passing-props-through-children) on how to do it.
You can also use the [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) and here's a tutorial on how to do it.

Comment: So by TextArea as the child of State and State as the child of App, can i send the component of TextArea to App ?

Comment: yes, please see the documentation of reference https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: Yes the data flow is always downwards. Thanks